# Ionic not loading on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using:

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

I have built an app with:

```
ionic build android
```

This builds the relevant `apk` file, that I can install to an Android devise.

I have tried a number of devises successfully:

```
Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 6.0.1
Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 5
```

However, when I try install it on the following, it seems to just hang when I launch the app:

```
Samsung Galaxy Tab with Android 4.4.2
```

I have added an alert to the top of the constructor in `app.components.ts`, but this does not get fired on the `Android 4.4.2` devise.

If anyone can offer any ideas I would appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: you can use `chrome://inspect/#devices` inside chrome, if you connect your phone using USB and enable USB debugging

Comment: Yes that makes sense. My problem unfortunately is my MacBook doesn't have USB port (just Thunderbolt 3) to attach with my Android devise. I will see if I can install an Android Emulator with 4.4.2. Do you think that's a good idea?

Comment: Flush your MacBook, and curse at it for not having a standard connector used in every other device. But I guess you can try using the Emulator to see if an error pops up. Are you adding the crosswalk plugin though?

Comment: I think that is the only option.. @PierreDuc crosswalk will be required if Android is _below_ 4.4

Comment: Haha, no usb is a pain for sure, and I don't feel like spending on an adapter. I don't use crosswalk. Do you know if I can get `chrome://inspect/#devices` to connect to an emulator?

Comment: yes you can.. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Thanks Suraj, however it appears to only support devices connected via usb.

Comment: no.. it will detect your emulator..once you run in one.. I speak from experience :P

Comment: Thanks for the help, will give it a try

Comment: I have my app running (and hanging) in the Android Emulator (Andy). However, when I go to `chrome://inspect/#devices`, there is no sign of it.

Comment: I also downloaded Chrome onto the Android Emulator, but `chrome://inspect` is not available. ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: not chrome within emulator.. the chrome in your mac..

Comment: It doesn't see the emulator either unfortunately. What emulator have you used in the past where this has worked? (perhaps it does not work with Andy).

Comment: It worked with the default Android studio emulator..you will see it in remote devices option.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give Android Studio a try.

Comment: that works. thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic doesnt provide support for 4.4.2 See [github issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6281)

Key points :

1. you can use [crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview)

Key Commands

```
ionic browser add crosswalk
```

2. when u will use this however angular date pipe will break.
   As per comment

> "Hello @windwp! Ionic 2 does not currently support the Android browser, although we do support chrome for Android. 
>   The date pipe uses the internationalization API which is not supported in older browsers such as the Android browser. 
>   Sorry for any hassle that causes you, and thanks for using Ionic!"

So possible solution is

a. use moment [angular2-moment]

```
{{myDate | amDateFormat:'LL'}}
```

This will work everywhere.

b. use [intl js polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-polyfill).